ConanException: Command 'apt-get update' failed
I'm using conan to handle libraries in my project, but I have a problem with it. After running conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
everything goes well until the end when I get an error:
ERROR: xorg/system: Error in system_requirements() method, line 28
    apt.install(["libx11-dev", "libx11-xcb-dev", "libfontenc-dev", "libice-dev", "libsm-dev", "libxau-dev", "libxaw7-dev",
    ConanException: Command 'apt-get update' failed

I tried installing those libraries manually and it worked fine, but the problem persists. I am trying to install OpenCv library for a Qt project, and my conanfile.txt contains the following lines:
[requires]
opencv/4.10.0
[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

I checked on conans site that opencv/4.10.0 is the correct way to add it to the file, and in conans profiles/default file I have the line tools.system.package_manager:mode=install. Conan worked fine just 8 months ago when I set up the last c++ project, but I don't know what to do now.
Can someone help?

appears related to permissions, and sudo might be required as mentioned on https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/16306

It might require tools.system.package_manager:sudo=True, see https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/tools/system/package_manager.html

That worked, thanks
